# Quartz scheduler shuts down before job execution

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

New to quartz scheduler. What I am trying to achieve is to fire one trigger in the future and then shutdown the scheduler. I am using `scheduler.shutdown(true)` for this, but it shuts down before executing the job. I have to call shutdown() as I am going to implement the scheduler in a web app.

**So how do I shutdown scheduler after job executes ?**

**JOB:**

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {

    public HelloJob(){
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
                System.out.println("Hello Quartz on " + new Date());    
            }
}
```

**Scheduler:**

```
public class QuartzTest {

    public void scheduleLoad(String time) {
        try {
            // Transform user input into a date
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
            Date scheduleDate = dateFormat.parse(time);

            // Print Current vs. Scheduled time/date
            System.out.println("Current time - " + new Date());
            System.out.println("Scheduled time - " + scheduleDate); 

            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
            Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

            // and start it off
            scheduler.start();

            // Define a job and tie it to a class
            JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
                    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .build();

            // Trigger job to run now and repeat every 10 secs
            SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .startAt(scheduleDate)
                    .forJob("job1","group1")
                    .build();

            // Schedule job using trigger
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

            // Shutdown the scheduler after job is executed
            scheduler.shutdown(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String runTime = "04/10/2013:20:07:00";
        QuartzTest quartz = new QuartzTest();
        quartz.scheduleLoad(runTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Current time - Wed Apr 10 20:06:31 IST 2013
Scheduled time - Wed Apr 10 20:07:00 IST 2013
[main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[main] INFO org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.1.7 created.
[main] INFO org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.7) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

[main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
[main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.7
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
```

**quartz.properties:**

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `scheduler.shutdown(true);`  It will wait for executing jobs to finish, but it will NOT wait for scheduled jobs to start and finish.  Your job is not starting before you shutdown the scheduler.  You could put a  `Thread.sleep(wait);`   before you shut it down.  To get your code to run as I understand you want it, remove this line (you basically don't ever need to shut down the scheduler):

```
 // Shutdown the scheduler after job is executed
 scheduler.shutdown(true);
```

Also, move this line so that it gets executed only once.  Where you put it, depends on your application, it could be in the main method for a standalone app, or in the init method of a Servlet or a Listener if running in a web application:

```
 // and start it off
 scheduler.start();
```

**Followup:**

I don't understand why you need to shut down Quartz.  What happens if another user needs to schedule a task? Are you planning on starting a different Quartz instance per each scheduled job? It would make more sense to just have it running and schedule tasks as needed.  That's the normal way to run Quartz.  You might be able to have it behave in the way you want, but it might be contrived.  If you really just want something that starts up and shuts down after the task runs, you might want to look at the Timer and TimerTask provided by the JDK. See example [here](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

Comment: Ok, but what if I cant predict what value 'wait' will be ? e.g.- In a web app, suppose I let users schedule jobs which will run only once, but after 5/3/4/2 days, how will I hard code `Thread.sleep(wait)` in my app ?

Comment: Normal practice would be for the quartz scheuduler to run for the lifetime of you application.  If you only need to execute one job and then stop then why use a scheduler at all?

Comment: @darrenmc Because that one job will be scheduled by the user for maybe executing after a month. And after that the thread should be killed ya ? What you are talking about is a cronTrigger right ? I will use a simpleTrigger

Comment: @AndresOlarte I think I'll go woth your 1st option i.e. 1 quartz instance for multiple scheduled jobs. Could you provide me an example for that ?

Comment: @kaustavdatta See changes above.

Comment: @kaustavdatta, to me it sounds like you actually don't need Quartz for the individual user jobs, but rather a job that will run every day, load the users' settings, and for all users that are supposed to run that day, run the batch job.
For that, you may let the Quartz run with a daily cron job.